# Creating a tty for Sensu with Python

Tags: python, linux, tty, sensu

Hello guys I'm trying to create a sensu check in python that requires a shell but is currently giving me a tty error.

```
cmd = '/usr/bin/pstorage stat |grep %s |grep failed' % hostname
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

Sensu by default doesn't have a tty so when it tries to execute the script

```
sudo /etc/sensu/plugins/diskauto.py --storage_name pool-01
```

the output is

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I already have the following sudo rule in place

```
Cmnd_Alias DRIVE_AUTOMATION=/apptio/scripts/diskauto.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `sudo` to not require a tty for certain cases.

Assuming `sensu` is running as the `sensu` user, add the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults:sensu !requiretty
```

Comment: Might be unrelated, but your ALIAS is for a different command than your example.